# В каких случаях поиск оправданно сделать POST, а не GET-запросом?

Tags: post, rest, get

Есть сервис, который автоматизирует интернет магазин. Для него нужно сделать REST-запрос, возвращающий товары, наименование которых содержит определенное слово. Больше сервис ничего не делает, т.е. простой поиск. В каких случаях это оправданно сделать POST, а не GET-запросом?
Вопрос возник, т.к. в одном обучающем материале это сделано POST-запросом, но при этом запрос ничего не меняет на сервере.

Answer (score 2):

Бывают случаи, когда HTTP GET менее подходит для получения данных. Примером является ситуация, когда большое количество данных должно быть записано в URL. Браузеры и веб-серверы могут иметь ограничения на длину URL, которые они обрабатывают без усечения или ошибки. URL-кодирование зарезервированных символов в адресе и строке запроса может значительно увеличить длину, в то время как HTTP-сервер Apache может обрабатывать до 4000 символов (8190 байт) в URL, Microsoft Internet Explorer ограничивает длину любого URL 2048 символами